# Moving data using firebase's db

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a pretty basic data structure that looks like:

```
festive-tiger
+city
     +brisbane
             +lat 100
             +long 100
```

What I would like to do is have as the top element "country" and a list of countries and then put the city underneath each country. I added "country" below festive-tiger and under country "australia", "new zealand", etc.

```
festive-tiger
+city
+country 
      +Australia
      +New Zealand
```

But i'm guessing i can't just drag city beneath "australia".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to *move* a node, neither in the Firebase Console nor through any of the SDKs or APIs.

But you can easily make a copy of the node and delete the original. In the UI, you can export the node by clicking the three-dotted button at the top of the data. Then import the file in the new location.